# Two maps from $S^1$ to $S^1$ are not homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm reading the book *Algebraic Topology from a Homotopical Viewpoint* but I don't understand why the $ n \in \mathbb{Z} $ in **Proposition 2.4.4** is unique. It suffices to prove that $ \widehat{\phi}_n $ and $ \widehat{\phi}_m $ are not homotopic where $$ \widehat{\phi}_k : \mathbb{S}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1\ \qquad \widehat{\phi}_n (e^{i2\pi t}) = e^{i2k\pi t} $$ for $ n \neq m $. Is this obvious ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If they were homotopic their lifts would end at the same spot.  They don't.

Comment: @Randall But in this book it does not define lift before this proposition.

Comment: View a (pointed) homotopy $F:S^1\times I\rightarrow S^1$, $\hat\varphi_n\simeq\hat\varphi_m$, by adjunction as a continuous family of maps $I\ni t\mapsto F_t:S^1\rightarrow S^1$. Apply the propositions to get a continuous family of maps $\varphi_t:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $t\mapsto\varphi_t(1)$ is a path in $\mathbb{R}$ from $\varphi_n(1)=n$ to $\varphi_m(1)=m$. However, since $F$ is pointed $\hat\varphi_t(1)=1\in S^1$ for all $t$. Hence $\varphi_t(1)\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $t$. Hence $\varphi_t(1)=n$ for all $t$. Hence $m=n$.

Comment: @Tyrone How to prove that $ t \mapsto \phi_t(1) $ is continuous ? and why the homotopy $ F $ of $ \widehat{\phi}_n $ and $ \widehat{\phi}_m $ must satisfy $ F(1, t) = 1\ \forall t\in I $ ?

Comment: Continuity  follows from the exponential law (section 1.3). It's not true that a homtopy $F$ *has* to satisfy $F(1,t)=1$ for all $t$, but using the methods of Theorem 2.4.2 you can show that you can always choose $F$ to satisfy this condition.

Comment: @Tyrone I still not understand how to use exponential law to prove it, could you explain more detail ? Thanks.

Comment: It is the map $I\rightarrow Map(S^1,S^1)\rightarrow S^1$, where the first map is the (continuous) adjoint of $F$ and the second map is the (continuous) evaluation $f\mapsto f(1)$.

Comment: @Tyrone Do you mean $ t \mapsto \varphi_t(1) $ is $ I \rightarrow M(S^1, S^1) \rightarrow S^1 $ ? But $ \varphi_t (1) \in \mathbb{R}, $ right ?. And could you point out that which property in Sec 1.3 you use? Furthermore, I don't know why we can choose $ F $ so that $ F(1,t) = 1\ \forall t\in I. $ Sorry, I'm just a beginner in Algebraic Topology, could you kindly write more detail ?

Comment: @MathFanatic, I'm sorry but you're asking me to recall details that I commented over a month ago. I'm afraid I'm far too busy this weekend to write a detailed answer. If I have time in the next week I will try to write something. In section 1.3 there seems to be a proposition and a theorem, either of which can be applied here.